# Compile Latex without Saving, and without Query

Tags: latex, auctex, tex

I know that I can disable the save query that comes after running `TeX-run-TeX` with `LaTeX`, `TeX` or actually probably any other NAME parameter (this is what happens when you invoke `TeX-command-master`, usually bound to <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, and then select `LaTeX` or `TeX` or whatever).  I did disable it, but what this does, is automatically save, so I can't compile without saving, unless I re-enable the annoying save query, after which I can let it not save.

What I would ideally want, is that when invoking `TeX-run-TeX` with whatever option on its own it never saves (I would have to manually save), and `TeX-command-run-all` always saves.

In `tex-buf.el`, for me it looks like setting `TeX-save-query` to `nil` will definitely cause the file to be automatically saved, so it seems kind of annoying for me to solve this problem in a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following advice makes `TeX-check-files` believe that no buffer is modified in `TeX-command-master`:

```el
(defun ad-TeX-command-master-wo-check (fun &rest args)
  "Deactivates `buffer-modified-p` in `TeX-check-files'."
  (cl-letf* ((old-TeX-check-files (symbol-function 'TeX-check-files))
             ((symbol-function 'TeX-check-files)
               `(lambda (&rest args)
                  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'buffer-modified-p) #'ignore))
                    (apply ,old-TeX-check-files args)))))
         (apply fun args)))


(advice-add 'TeX-command-master :around #'ad-TeX-command-master-wo-check)
```

You can use it with `TeX-save-query` on or off.

If `TeX-save-query` is on `TeX-command-master` does not save on compilation and `TeX-command-run-all` does save.

Comment: Thanks!  This looked pretty good, but when I tried it out, compiling didn't do anything, or rather it probably recompiled the unedited file.  Weird.

Comment: @Berber Yes. Compiling the old code is exactly what you asked for. Maybe, you actually wanted to ask something different.

Comment: @Berber Perhaps you should just set "Command On" to Buffer and then type `C-c C-c`. You find that check box in the Command menu.

Comment: What I meant, was to compile the code in the buffer, without saving the code in the buffer to the file that is associated to the buffer.  But now I see the problem: If I compile the master file, it will compile the old code, as it LaTeX reads the file, and not the buffer.  So I guess what I ultimately want, which is to compile what is in the buffer, is not possible in this way.  Especially if I invoked the command from a file that isn't the master file, the `\input{file}` line will obviously read a file, and never a buffer.  Thank you very much for your code, it helped me understand things!